# What is type in auth_item table in rbac Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have been trying to setup `rbac` `DbManager` following the [Yii2 GUide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#configuring-authmanager-with-dbmanager). So, I have create tables in database as their instruction using the `migrate` command. I found that there are few `tables` created. Now my problem is that there is column `type` in the table `auth_item`. I do not understand why it is used?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is simply the auth item type :

> The type of the item. This should be either `TYPE_ROLE` or `TYPE_PERMISSION`.

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-item.html

Comment: thanks for the information. I got it that's mean `TYPE_ROLE` = 1 and `TYPE_PERMISSION` = 2

Comment: Why the value for both route and permission is the same (2)? How do we distinguish them?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign this item to someone as a role, then you should choose #1 because, as per the Yii Documentation, `TYPE_ROLE = 1`.

Likewise, to give permission to someone (User) to access the item, you should choose #2 as `TYPE_PERMISSION = 2`.